# Prevent Windows Terminal Title from changing

Tags: windows, terminal

I am trying out Windows Terminal. I use bash and want the Windows Terminal Tab title to remain as cwd (which is initially set by bash) instead of changing since while using multiple tabs they become indistinguishable. If I run say `npm run start` in bash directly, the title (in title bar) remains as cwd but if I try to use it via Windows Terminal the tab title changes to npm which I don't want.

My `.bashrc`

```
if test -f /etc/profile.d/git-sdk.sh
then
    TITLEPREFIX=SDK-${MSYSTEM#MINGW}
else
    TITLEPREFIX=$MSYSTEM
fi

if test -f ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
then
    . ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
else
    # PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]' # set window title
    # PS1='\[\e]0;\W\a\]\[\033]0;$PWD\007\]' # set window title (full path)
    PS1='\[\e]0;\W\a\]' # set window title (only directory name)
    PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'       # change to green
    PS1="$PS1"'\u '             # user@host<space>
    # PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'       # change to purple
    # PS1="$PS1"'$MSYSTEM '          # show MSYSTEM
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[33m\]'       # change to brownish yellow
    PS1="$PS1"'\w'                 # current working directory
    if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
    then
        GIT_EXEC_PATH="$(git --exec-path 2>/dev/null)"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${GIT_EXEC_PATH%/libexec/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${COMPLETION_PATH%/lib/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="$COMPLETION_PATH/share/git/completion"
        if test -f "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
        then
            . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-completion.bash"
            . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
            PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[36m\]'  # change color to cyan
            PS1="$PS1"'`__git_ps1`'   # bash function
        fi
    fi
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[0m\]'        # change color
    PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
    PS1="$PS1"'$ '                 # prompt: always $
fi

MSYS2_PS1="$PS1"               # for detection by MSYS2 SDK's bash.basrc

# Evaluate all user-specific Bash completion scripts (if any)
if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
then
    for c in "$HOME"/bash_completion.d/*.bash
    do
        # Handle absence of any scripts (or the folder) gracefully
        test ! -f "$c" ||
        . "$c"
    done
fi

export PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e]0;\W\a\]\[\033[01;32m\]\u \[\033[00m\]\[\033[01;00m\]\w\n$ '
# echo -ne '\033]0;New Title\a'
```

My Windows Terminal `settings.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",
  "defaultProfile": "{00000000-0000-0000-ba54-000000000002}",
  "copyOnSelect": false,
  "copyFormatting": false,
  "profiles": {
    "defaults": {
      "fontSize": 10
    },
    "list": [
      {
        "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
        "name": "Windows PowerShell",
        "commandline": "powershell.exe",
        "hidden": false
      },
      {
        "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
        "name": "Command Prompt",
        "commandline": "cmd.exe",
        "hidden": false
      },
      {
        "guid": "{b453ae62-4e3d-5e58-b989-0a998ec441b8}",
        "hidden": false,
        "name": "Azure Cloud Shell",
        "source": "Windows.Terminal.Azure"
      },
      {
        "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-ba54-000000000002}",
        "commandline": "%PROGRAMFILES%/git/usr/bin/bash.exe -i -l",
        "icon": "%PROGRAMFILES%/Git/mingw64/share/git/git-for-windows.ico",
        "name": "Bash",
        "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%"
      }
    ]
  },
  "schemes": [],
  "actions": [
    { "command": { "action": "copy", "singleLine": false }, "keys": "ctrl+c" },
    { "command": "paste", "keys": "ctrl+v" },
    { "command": "find", "keys": "ctrl+shift+f" },
    {
      "command": {
        "action": "splitPane",
        "split": "auto",
        "splitMode": "duplicate"
      },
      "keys": "alt+shift+d"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

windows terminal has two tag to change this

```
"tabTitle": "yourtitle",
"suppressApplicationTitle": true
```

so in your case, maybe you can write like this

```
{
    "guid": "{00000000-0000-0000-ba54-000000000002}",
    "commandline": "%PROGRAMFILES%/git/usr/bin/bash.exe -i -l",
    "icon": "%PROGRAMFILES%/Git/mingw64/share/git/git-for-windows.ico",
    "name": "Bash",
    "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%",
    "tabTitle": "cwd",
    "suppressApplicationTitle": true
}
```

Comment: You could add a link to the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/tab-title

Comment: with the config above the title will be set to the string "cwd" and wont change on changing directory which is not I want.

Comment: This might not be correct answer to this question but it helped me to solve my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it using the GUI

In "Settings" select your Profile and click on "Advanced"

[image: Select your Profile and click on "Advanced"]

Then change the slide button of "Suppress title changes" to "On"

[image: Then change the slide button of "Suppress title changes" to "On"]